# Melhorar função javascript que habilita checkbox

Tags: javascript

Em meu formulario tenho inputs que so poderão ser editados após uma confirmação do checkbox correspondente, tenho ele a funciona neste momento:

http://jsfiddle.net/thallysondias/rwn73gnp/

utilizo a função do javascritp:

```
document.getElementById('check-praia').onchange = function() {
document.getElementById('input-praia').disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

Contudo possuo vários campos, e para cada campo novo tenho que editar o ficheiro .js e adicionar uma nova função.

Como posso deixar este codigo mais inteligente, digo, por exemplo:

```
PEGAR_ID_DO_CHECKBOX.onchange = function(){
PEGAR_ID_DO_INPUT.disable = !this.checked;
};
```

A minha ideia era poder pegar automaticamente o id do check e do input e inserir na tag.
Sempre que determinada checkbox for clicada ela altera o valor do input.

Visualize o jsfiddle para melhor entendimento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A solução

Como o padrão de hierarquia é muito claro (sempre há um label de classe "checkbox-proximidade" englobando um checkbox; o ID desse checkbox está relacionado com o ID do `<input />`), podemos fazer um código que tira proveito dessas relações:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox-proximidade");
for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) labels[i].children[0].addEventListener("change", function(e){
    document.getElementById("input-" + e.srcElement.id.split("-")[1]).disabled = !this.checked;
});
```

O [JSFiddle modificado está aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/xqf785dw/).

## Funcionamento

Em `labels`, capturamos todos os elementos `<label class="checkbox-proximidade">`, que possuem os checkboxes.

Para cada um deles (através da instrução `for`), navegamos até seu único elemento-filho (`children[0]`) e, nele, adicionamos um *listener* de evento *change*.

Cada *callback* de *listener*, ao executar, busca por um elemento cujo ID termine com o mesmo sufixo pós-hífen (`split("-")[1]`) termine com o mesmo sufixo do `<input />`, e habilitamos/desabilitamos baseados no estado atual desse `<input />` (por sinal, apontado por `e.srcElement`).

**Obs**.: repare que esta solução pressupõe, além dos padrões de hierarquia já definidos, que cada ID conterá apenas **um** hífen! Caso utilize mais que um, basta modificar a função de *callback* para:

```
function(e){
    var arr_aux = e.srcElement.id.split("-"); // Obtém o array de partes do sufixo.
    arr_aux.splice(0, 1); // Remove a primeira parte, que corresponde a "check".
    // O join(str) une novamente os elementos do array em uma string,
    // ligando-os com a string (str) especificada:
    document.getElementById("input-" + arr_aux.join("-")).disabled = !this.checked;
}
```

Comment: Exatamente Rui Pimentel, muito obrigado, por acaso podia explicar um pouco o código, para eu poder entender melhor e poder aprender?

Comment: Com certeza. Modifiquei a resposta! :)

Comment: Muito obrigado, compreendi a logica, nao sabia que dava para fazer isso. :D